# Removing file extension with Replace fails if there is a single quote in file name

Tags: replace, preg-replace

have have a list list of jpg associated with names and I am using the replace function to remove the extension 
     `$withoutExt = preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $filename);`
which I grabbed from another post on this site [How to remove extension from string (only real extension!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395882/how-to-remove-extension-from-string-only-real-extension) .  it works perfect except for people with O'Reilly or O'Neil, names that have an apostrophe in them.  any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Works perfectly for me, like this example:

```
<?php

$filename = 'O\'Reilly.jpg';
$withoutExt = preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $filename);
echo $withoutExt . "\n";
```

Output: `O'Reilly`

Try to print out the `$filename` before replace to ensure that is a matchable string according with the regexp.

Comment: Thanks for the input, i see what you are doing here but I am grabbing these from a list of names which would make it difficult to parse each name and if it has a ' in it place the escape character \ before it, I may have to play around with this a bit. Was hoping there was a way to do it in the regex.  Thanks i'll see if I can get it to work with enumerating through a list of names...