# SQL database table creation with variable

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a project, and I have to use sql. The variable `$file_name` needs to be the table name, but when i try this:

```
$sqlTableCreate = "CREATE TABLE ". $file_name . "( 
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(50),
    reg_date TIMESTAMP
)";
```

The table does not create. I checked by using this:

```
if ($sqlConnection->query($sqlTableCreate) === TRUE) {  
    echo 'Created Sucessfully';
} else {
    echo 'Table does not create.';
}
```

I get `'Table does not create'` when trying to use this. Help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you show how `$sqlConnection` is created? are you using `PDO` or `mysqli`

Comment: You need to get the *actual* error from MySQL. It isn't clear which API you're using, so you'll have to look at the docs for that API to determine how to return real error messages.

Comment: There is not actual error from MySQL. It just doesn't create. I am using MySQLi

Comment: Consult the docs [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php).

Comment: what is the output if you add `print $sqlConnection->error;` to the `else` clause ?

Comment: Can you check anyway, whether the table is created already? (If created once, subsequent queries will fail with error.)

Comment: agree with @TareqMahmood; that could be a bummer.

Comment: I have checked the database and there is nothing there besides ones that i have just recently checked. I will post the output of the errors in a minute.

Comment: SQL error: Unknown database 'currentScan'

Comment: @Robert What's the value of `$file_name`?

Comment: @Robert, that means you have made mistake while selecting database when creating the connection. Showing your codes for creating connection will be more helpful,

Comment: @Barmar $file_name = 'currentScan.csv'; but it does change when the file is uploaded to the server.

Comment: @Robert, that's could be the problem. You are trying to create a table named `currentScan.csv` which your DB engine thinking that `currentscan` is the DB name and `csv` is the table name which obviously doesn't exits.

Comment: @Barmar, that's the problem! :)

Comment: so, how would i drop the .csv? i need to have the table called 'currentScan'. When i posted the error, it said `Unknown database 'correctscan'`. i am not exactly sure why it says database.

Comment: @Robert 'currentScan.csv' will try to create a table named `csv` in db `currentScan`, so it wont work if there is any db named `currentScan` and you are properly connected to it.

Comment: There is no database called currentScan. The database is called PrimeSelect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your filename contains a extension, but I suspect you just want to use the name without the extension as the name of the table. You can use the `basename` function to remove the extension.

```
$sqlTableCreate = "CREATE TABLE ". basename($file_name, ".csv") . "( 
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(50),
    reg_date TIMESTAMP
)";
```

If there can be different extensions, and you want to remove them more generally, see

[How to remove extension from string (only real extension!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395882/how-to-remove-extension-from-string-only-real-extension)

Comment: Need to make sure, if there is any other file type expected?

Comment: I've added a link to another question that shows how to remove extensions in general.

Comment: There is not. There is only a .csv extension allowed to be uploaded to the site. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issue with your posted query but couple things may be wrong

Make sure that there is no table exists with that same name. You can use `IF NOT EXISTS` marker to be sure like

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS". $file_name . "(
```

2. make sure that the variable `$file_name` is not empty. Else, you are passing a null identifier in `CREATE TABLE` statement; which will not succeed.

Per your comment: you have `$file_name = 'currentScan.csv';`

That's the problem here. You are trying to create a table named `currentScan.csv` which your DB engine thinking that `currentscan` is the DB name and `.csv` is the table name which obviously doesn't exits and so the error.

Answer (score -1):

first check your database connection and change your query with given below :

```
$sqlTableCreate = "CREATE TABLE ". $file_name . " ( 
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(50),
reg_date TIMESTAMP
)";
```

Comment: The OP's query is fine, and I see no change here?

Comment: My database connection is fine, but i am just not able to create the table.

Comment: Does the space matter?