# How to get the filename without the extension in php?

Tags: php, csv

I'm using the following code to display the name of a CSV file before the contents of the CSV file are displayed on a PHP page. It works well and displays the name of the file as it should:

CODE:

```
    #$result .= '<h3>'.$prog.'</h3>'.PHP_EOL; // OLD STYLE
    $result .= '<h3>'.$prog. ' '.$_POST['filename'].'</h3>'.PHP_EOL; // NEW STYLE
    $result .= '</div>'.PHP_EOL;
    $result .= $contents.PHP_EOL;
```

Problem is, I don't want the file name to display the extension (in my code example, it is .csv)

Can anyone assist in the right code needed to remove the extension (.CSV)...?

Comment: It's asked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395882/how-to-remove-extension-from-string-only-real-extension

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove extension from string (only real extension!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395882/how-to-remove-extension-from-string-only-real-extension)

Comment: If you know the file extension is CSV you can just remove CSV from the string, or the last four characters. Why make it any harder?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php

Comment: @samwest , For question +1 .

Answer (score 3):

// Use this code I hope it's useful ..
=> The `basename()` function returns the filename

```
<?php
$path = "filename.CSV"; // set your file name 

//Show filename with file extension
echo basename($path) ."<br/>";

//Show filename without file extension
echo basename($path,".CSV");
?>
```

OutPut :- 
filename.CSV
filename

OR

// you also use  `pathinfo()` function .

```
$file_name = pathinfo('filename');

echo $file_name['dirname'], "\n";
echo $file_name['basename'], "\n";
echo $file_name['extension'], "\n";
echo $file_name['filename'], "\n"
```

==> Check this Demo Link :- 
https://eval.in/930790

Comment: I tried the following code: $info = pathinfo($file);
$file_name =  basename($file,'.'.$info['extension']);
echo $file_name;    - but this didn't work

Comment: Post your file name and which type of output you want .

Comment: @SamWest, i update my answer and set one output Link as per your comment code please check it , i hope it's useful .

Comment: And if you have any problem than please update your question and post you full code , So we can help you .