# How to parse a mostly consistent filename into meaningful parts?

Tags: php, regex, filenames, text-parsing, preg-split

I have filenames like:

```
1234_56_78 A_FAIRLY_SHORT_TITLE_D.pdf
```

Luckily, the file naming is pretty consistent, but I can't absolutely guarantee that someone didn't use a space where they should have used an underscore.

With this in mind, I want to parse the string and extract the following details:

```
$project_no = '1234
$series_no = '56
$sheet_no = '78'
$revision = 'D'
$title = 'A Fairly Short Title'
```

Presently, I use the following to grab this info:

```
$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'][$i];
$filename = preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $filename);
$parts = preg_split( "(_| )", $filename );
$project_no = $parts[0];
$series_no = $parts[1];
$sheet_no = $parts[2];
$revision = end($parts);
```

`$title` is simply everything that's left over after removing `$parts[0]` `$parts[1]`, `$parts[2]`, and `end($parts)`, but how should I express that?

I thought I might be able to use

```
$title = implode(' ',\array_diff_key($parts, [0,1,2,end($parts)]));
```

But this doesn't remove the `$revision` bit at the end...

```
$title = FLOOR AS PROPOSED D
```

What am I missing, and am I unnecessarily over-complicating this?

Comment: [array_pop()](https://www.php.net/array_pop) and [array_shift()](https://www.php.net/array_shift) are your friends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`array_diff_key`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-key.php) looks at key comparison of both arrays. [`end()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) just moves the internal pointer of the array and is actually useless since the value returned from it can't be used in computing difference between 2 arrays' keys.

Current comparison behaves as

```
array_diff_key([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7], [0,1,2,'D'])
```

which looks *key* wise as:

```
   array_diff_key([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7], [0,1,2,3])
```

Hence, the end result of `implode` is concatenation of `4,5,6,7` keys' values.

To make the second parameter array values as keys, you can use [`array_flip`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) to make keys as values and values as keys with the below expression:

```
$title = implode(' ',\array_diff_key($parts, array_flip([0,1,2,count($parts)-1])));
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/J6b5r

Answer (score 1):

I fear you are over-complicating this.  I think a single `preg_match()` call is the most direct way to parse your string.

It looks like you grabbed the regex pattern from https://stackoverflow.com/a/2395905/2943403 to trim the extension from your filename; however, I recommend using a regex function when a single non-regex function serves the same purpose.

```
pathinfo($filename', PATHINFO_FILENAME)
```

Now that the extension has been removed, let's move on to the parsing.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/IGIbm))

```
$filename = '1234_56_78 A_FAIRLY_SHORT_TITLE_D.pdf';
preg_match('~([^ _]+)[ _]([^ _]+)[ _]([^ _]+)[ _](.+)[ _](\S)~', pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_FILENAME), $m);

var_export([
    'project_no' => $m[1],
    'series_no' => $m[2],
    'sheet_no' => $m[3],
    'title' => str_replace('_', ' ', $m[4]),
    'revision' => $m[5],
]);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'project_no' => '1234',
  'series_no' => '56',
  'sheet_no' => '78',
  'title' => 'A FAIRLY SHORT TITLE',
  'revision' => 'D',
)
```

---

If you are deadset on using `preg_split()`, then the pattern becomes super simple, but there is a little more mopping up to do.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/dtShK))

```
$filename = '1234_56_78 A_FAIRLY_SHORT_TITLE_D.pdf';
$m = preg_split('~ |_~', pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_FILENAME));
$revision = array_pop($m);

var_export([
    'project_no' => $m[0],
    'series_no' => $m[1],
    'sheet_no' => $m[2],
    'title' => implode(' ', array_slice($m, 3)),
    'revision' => $revision,
]);
// same output as earlier snippet
```